# Exclude an div element from background overlay

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a block with overlay hover effect (default: weak black background color - Hover: none black background) and an icon and text in the middle that stays in the same state all the way.

How do i get the icon and text to stay in the same state (no hover effect)?

Ive tried several rules to the overlay div and the icon div without any luck.

Is there any css rule that provide some kind of exclusion?

I managed to get it to work by adding them outside the divs that has overlay background, but it didnt work out well as the hover effect breaks when you hover over the icon and text.

Here is the code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEMUM4N9T30Q

```
<style>
.media-front-top-picture{
    background-image: url("");
    height:500px;
}
     .media-front-top-icon{
        content: url(");
        width: 130px;
        margin: auto;
        padding-top: 200px;
        opacity: 1;
     }
     .media-front-txt{
        font-size: 22px;
        letter-spacing: 8px;
        color: white;
        margin-top: 15px;
     }
.media-front-bottom-picture{
    background-image: url("h");
    height:500px;
}
     .media-front-bottom-icon{
        content: url("");
        width:130px;
        margin: auto;
        padding-top: 200px;
     }

.media-picture-container {
    position: relative;
}
.media-picture-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
}

.media-picture-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
</style>





<div class="body-media">
<div class="media-picture-container">
    <div class="media-front-top-picture" style="border-bottom:4px solid white;">
    <div class="media-front-top-icon"></div>
    <div class="media-front-txt">VIDEOS</div>
    <div class="media-picture-overlay"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="media-picture-container">
     <div class="media-front-bottom-picture" style="border-bottom:4px solid white;">
     <div class="media-front-bottom-icon"></div>
     <div class="media-front-txt">PICTURES</div>
     <div class="media-picture-overlay"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

for the classes on your icons, add a z-index higher than a z-index you add to the overlay class.  Also, make sure to make the icon classes have `position:relative` so the z-index is applied.  Note, my example only applies this solution to one icon, its up to you to apply it elsewhere.

Example:

```
 .media-front-top-icon{
    content: url("example.com");
    width: 130px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index:10;
    position:relative;
 }

.media-picture-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
    z-index:5;
}
```

Comment: Awesome and thanks! This worked excatly how i wanted it to, had to read myself up on the z-index now and found it it changes the orders of the elements, which is pretty neat. CSS never fails to amaze me.

Comment: @Normar sweet.  Don't forget to accept and upvote answers you like so people keep answering your questions.  :)